# Throwing the dice, sum of the points

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

> We are throwing the die (original cube for the board games). How many are ways to get the sum of the points equal to $n$ ?

I've heard this problem today in the morning and still can't deal with it, which is tiring. The only way I see it, is that I am looking for the number of solutions of equations: $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = n$ for all possible $k$, where $1\le x_i\le 6$ for all $1\le i\le k$. So if I find the coefficient before $x^n$ in expansion to series this sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^n (x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^k=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\right)^k$$ it will be over. But I completely don't know how to do that. Or maybe there is a simpler solution for this problem?

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107329/ways-of-getting-a-number-with-n-dice-each-with-k-sides/107709#107709

Comment: To simplify the computations, one could include every $k\geqslant0$ in the sum in the LHS since the additional terms do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^n$ and note that the result is $1/(1-z)$ with $z=x+\cdots+x^6$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland It seems that here the number of throws is not specified. Unlike in [the answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107329/ways-of-getting-a-number-with-n-dice-each-with-k-sides/107709#107709) you indicate, or am I missing something?

Comment: @did You are quite right, I simply missed that point. I'll leave my comment up anyways. Perhaps it will prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of ways is $a(n)$ then $$a(n) = a(n-1)+ a(n-2) +a(n-3)+a(n-4)+a(n-5)+a(n-6)$$  starting with $a(0)=1$, and $a(n)=0$ for $-5 \le n \le -1$.

So the generating function is $$\frac{1}{1-x-x^2-x^3-x^4-x^5-x^6}$$ and you want the coefficient of $x^n$.

With an offset this is [OEIS A001592](http://oeis.org/A001592) (Hexanacci numbers).