# Choose k elements from [1..n] without replacement - how to bound max distance between two elements?

Tags: probability

Given a sequence $n$ of sequential numbers 1 to n, choose $k$ of them without resampling and call then $X_2$ to $X_{k+1}$. Let $X_{1} = 0$ and $X_{k+2} = n+1$. Is there any good bound on

$$P(\exists_{i} |X_i-X_{i+1}| > l)$$

for some $l$?

Comment: I am not sure why the question is as stated, but the probability is $1$ if $k \le n$ and $0$ if $k \gt n$, by considering $i=k+2$ and $j=k+1$.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I want to know the probability that the distance between to elements is > L for some n/k < L < n-k.  At a higher level, I want to know the probability that these $X_i$s aren't skewed towards one end of the other.

Comment: My point was that the $X_{k+1}=0$ and $X_{k+2}=n+1$ distort the question, unless you require $i,j \le k$

Comment: Ugh, right. Sorry. I'm looking at the distance between adjacent elements. See my edit

Comment: But for $i=k+1$ the absolute difference is $n+1$?

Comment: Ok, my fault again.  $X_0=0$.  The extra $X_i$s simply are there so that we count the edges of distribution

Answer (score 1):

There are ${n\choose k}$ ways to select the numbers $X_i$.

The number of selections with $\sup_i|X_i-X_{i+1}|\leq l$ 
 is the number of ways to roll an $l$-sided die $k+1$ times and have 
the total come out to $n+1$. From the inclusion-exclusion 
principle this is 
$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor (n-k)/l \rfloor} (-1)^i{k+1\choose i}{n-il\choose k}$,
see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107329/ways-of-getting-a-number-with-n-dice-each-with-k-sides/107709#107709).

The number of selections with $\sup_i|X_i-X_{i+1}|> l$ is 
therefore $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor (n-k)/l \rfloor} (-1)^{i+1}{k+1\choose i}{n-il\choose k}$,
and the desired probability is 
$$\mathbb{P}(\sup_i|X_i-X_{i+1}|> l)={1\over{n\choose k}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor (n-k)/l \rfloor} 
(-1)^{i+1}{k+1\choose i}{n-il\choose k}.$$