# Rolling $n$ times with an $m$-sided dice. Closed, finite formula for the distribution of the sum?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

My current idea is the following: practically we want to get the distribution of the sum of $n$-times of a discrete uniform distribution between $1,...,m$ .

It is practically the discrete convolution of these, which is a multiplication in the space of the Laplace/Fourier/$z$-transformations. Going in this direction I found complicated formulas whose de-transformation was already hopeless. (I could write them here on need.)

Was it a good direction? Maybe somebody knows the formula, or can show me a better way?

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107329/ways-of-getting-a-number-with-n-dice-each-with-k-sides/107709#107709  But it ain't pretty.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! I flagged this post as duplicate.

Comment: Glad to help. I will add my vote to close.