# Score-beating probability question...

Tags: probability

So I've got a problem I'm not sure how to solve.

Let's say I roll a die 50 times. Whatever value the face shows, I add to my score until I've rolled the die 50 times.

What I want to know is, what is the probability that I exceed some target score, X, after I have completed all 50 rolls. For example, what is the chance I've beaten a score of 190 after those 50 rolls?

Comment: You would have to iterate through all the $6^50$ possible events to find out the score of each event, with a probability of $\frac 16 ^{50}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability generating function can be used, which is:

\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= \left(\frac{x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6}{6}\right)^{50}
\end{align*}

for rolling the die 50 times.

We need to collect all the $[x^n]$ for $n>190$, which means:

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}\left(\text{sum}>190\right) &= \frac{498514565661112487515719367882893965}{4989390601634346053352713583065038848} \\
  &\approx 0.0999149205712251
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't get this.  What is $x$ here if its the number you want to get more than then P(190) doesn't give me the answer you posted.  I may be misinterpreting the answer can you expand it to explain where your formula comes from?

Comment: $x$ is just a formal variable. We are collecting and adding all the coefficients of $x^n$ where $n>190$ after expanding that polynomial, which was done by a computer. Read about generating functions to know more.

Comment: This link has a general summation formula: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107329/ways-of-getting-a-number-with-n-dice-each-with-k-sides