# Probability that the sum of n different dice is greater or equal than x

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Consider you are given n different dice. Each dice can have up to m sides with [1;m] eyes on the side.

What is the probability for a given set of different dice and an integer x, that the sum of all eyes after throwing each dice once is greater than or equal to x.

Example:

x = 6

2 dice, two D6.

P(X >= x) = 0.5

I assume there is no closed form formula to compute this?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107329/ways-of-getting-a-number-with-n-dice-each-with-k-sides

Comment: As an aside, the probability that the sum of two standard fair d6 will be greater than or equal to $6$ will be $\frac{26}{36}$, not $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @AlbertoSaracco your numbers are incorrect.  Greater or equal to $7$ would be $\frac{6+5+4+3+2+1}{36}=\frac{21}{36}\neq \frac{1}{2}$ and greater or equal to $6$ would be $\frac{5+6+5+4+3+2+1}{36}=\frac{26}{36}\neq \frac{23}{36}$

Comment: Matii P., your link is for n dice with k sides, meaning there are n equal dice. I have different dice, not only one kind.

Comment: @JMoravitz poi are totally right.